# HTML5 camera on video element filter not copying to canvas

Tags: html5-video, html5-canvas

I am making a new collage [application](http://www.lab.kaiserapps.com/webrtc/) using google chromes new WebRTC features that let me access the camera in javascript. I have been able to put the camera feed on a video element, take snapshots of the camera and store them in variables and them draw them onto my canvas.

My new problem is that even when the css -webkit-filter is changed on the video element with css (by clicking the video preview), the copied data is raw and not filtered. Is there any way to copy the draw the filtered data from the video element? or to draw a filter onto a region in a canvas?

Comment: It is CSS3-filters; that's why it is not copying over <canvas> surface ---- did you check SVG filters ??

Comment: I just took a peek, could only find one example http://goo.gl/dYOzq and even then the filter looks like a lot of work to try apply it to regions on a canvas.